# Cannot call a bootstrap modal via javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to Bootstrap and trying to learn how to show a modal window via a link click event. But it does not show anything with the following code and console errors none.

The whole logic is included in the `<head>` element as follows. What I need to do is show a modal window when user click on the Sign In link in the navigation bar.

```
<head>
    <title>Sample Web Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="compiled/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="compiled/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="compiled/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="modal fade" id="loginBox" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Sign In</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="User Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="doLogon">Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- ************** THIS IS NOT CALLED WHEN CLICKED ??? **************** -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#logonLink').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#loginBox').modal({
                keyboard: false,
                backdrop: static
            });
        });

        $('#doLogon').on('click', function(e) {
            alert('Thank you for Signing In');
            $('#logonBox').modal('hide');
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Here is the code in the Sign In link:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" id="logonLink"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Sign In</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can call the modal window using Bootstrap. But this pure JavaScript calling always fail.

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Thanks.

**Update: I figured out that following code is in question which is a JQuery. I don't know if the syntax is 100% correct.**

Link:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" id="logonLink"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Sign In</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#logonLink').on('click', function(e) {
                $('#loginBox').modal({
                    keyboard: false,
                    backdrop: static
                });
            });

            $('#doLogon').on('click', function(e) {
                alert('Thank you for Signing In');
                $('#logonBox').modal('hide');
            });
</script>
```

Comment: your html should be within the `<body>` tag

Comment: Moved the whole modal code and script code to the body. But same result. Nothing is shown.

Comment: what exactly have you moved? can you please write your code on jsFiddle or codepen?

Comment: All Bootstrap code and script code above to the beginning of the body tag.

Comment: I think the problem is with the scrip and/or Sign In link combination. I tried to show an alert window for the click event. It also fails and I suspect that script calling is failed. I'm not familiar with jQuery syntax for script calling.

Comment: please create a jsFiddle of the code you have, so it´s easier to see and recreate what's going on, otherwise it can be difficult

Comment: Hi, I'm not aware how to create jsFiddle. Anyway I found the code in question as shown in the original post as an update. Can you please refer to it?

Comment: I worked when I moved the script code below the Sign In link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginBox">
  Login
</button>
```

Simply use "login link" this way. No scripts.